# Does argument-dependent lookup also include overload set in inaccessible bases?

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-control, argument-dependent-lookup

Here's a simple [example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAGykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CIWGRLDFxAKy2mPZFDEIETMQEOT5%2BAXaYDlmNzQQlEdGxCckKTS1teVy2EwOhQ%2BUjlQCUtqhexMjsHObxocjeWADUJvFuBF4p9GfYJhoAgvcPXhlGx8xsCilM28fj6DOVkezwImBY1yYYLOFwAnilGKxMMcACq3Z7jYheBzHAhcY4gY4pYioMEOTDoVHPEwAdmBTxpABEgdTHmCIQZoecCPDEWwqfE7o9MdiCLizNS6c9jjLceDIVy3EwvERjgBJBhYVTox6y/4ELE40JhYgE3FcGFowXS2W0%2Bl64l4ABuUPYNr1MvZCswMOVqrVOoeHuDx2ImAAjl48GGFBANVrTvFmUn1St3R6TJUrFmGBg8ApRMRAZVmSXjlRiHhXMc0AxxphVMSawJxlSzIljsBMAQILXW8bYuYOwQVh9UA3tikCOm9XaZyGw5diAxcSzdSHacz1zLN2uGcn6aD5ZyfdzeZ9kSjSLjz0jjnJAyKcQR4maCBLzlbsCAQF6T8cB2IGENFua93xhB9BR/P9XQAhgTRhC1rRBKUUIPVkHidVA8EpfhUAgNMUPtWU%2BzFF8YSoMQlAAfR5BEwKuG5zlCAhryoWhUChdFBWOJ05yZPc9T9VBePxM5GU7btgNuCAnTTeJiJlYTeLMRMJK7adziQ7BZPkw8BJBR4WOOFgmFCAjTilAyHg4NZaE4SpeD8DgtFIVBODcaxrH%2BDYtmRPYeFIAhNFstYAGsQEkSQADouHiAAOOKuC4RJEkqRIAE4MukeyOEkJyQrczheAUEANCCkK1jgWAYEQFBUAhOhYnISg0Ea%2Bg4kOQxgForEGDC0gsCdPBtgANSrAB3AB5BFnMCmhaDBYhSogKJCqiUJmlhThAo25hiFhKaom0bpgu4Xg2rYQQpoYWhtpc3gsFMoxxAewbo1O51MFKt6G26FUdlcljakK2g8CiYgto8LBCoNPAWB22y%2BAMYAFHGzBptmxGZEEEQxHYKQcfkJQ1EK3QZgMIwUC8yx9HB0rYAvEAqBYVinRGA0vH6lY1lQKcsh%2BgBaAFxNMSxrDMKIStqT7nAgVwpj8GZggWMoKnydJMgERWNcKLJBjVkYZi6HoBD6SZPHaPQTfqc35lKYY4mNuYded/oDcdiQ1gUXzti9/QHIKt73I4Y5VHixJBcSSQa0p4BjggTnuYT3BCBIU4zHiLgVl4M6tCqpA2pSJqyAoXsGuLjqQFR5gUgUBBSUGzBhrGyaZsYbGFqWla1revatux/uDqOk6HGxy7GAIG67sKp7ute1z8DDHp2Z%2B1y/uQAHseB3LXLBiGoYwQHc8rBHzrWdimFR9HMY786ibx8QUqJxQVHUN7dACOPqfF2n94ZqATMWZsw5n1MKPM3L8xbJwYWBBARJjFlYSwktpZ1CyC4TUOtJDVBVg7JYcR4ipE1vULB1QChawYB7fBCQahoLNi7S2eRsG0Nlg0OYVD1aEPGP0Uhsx3aq09vEb2vsCZ2UDqQZyrkQ5hwjlHGOwBkDIATkncBKd8BEFNAFHOFUHoQIipUcquV8qkARlFaKiQNA0niGYDK8VJA2KztlCRhUQ4lT0HnJG1U6obAICkFULVy7tViOEJEnBw6R2jrHbqyiwHaIpGnSs6A9D8FxqIJ%2B0gUnEzfmTPQE1IYpEqgHDgjlnHB04FNFUfixSoCoDIiJMcurvETrEhOHggmaMztnXOhSIBIB8VUgJRcS4hLYGEyJLAFBOiUU6LgGVoonnGLweJGicLJNkI/AmyRMmv1Jh/fwpA8lMAKboopJTJG8BDhU3xKpjg1LqXIzsiiYlc1URANpldYgZ2sdojxECECYCYFgOIBEinGIRpUSo0V4gZXbDSDQXBKhwsSPFDQyRzlFQ4G48qvzwogAhdFCOXAI7xXivEeIkh4gaEsUU%2BIQcpHFR0fnMRHAzB0ouQynFpB2bLXQZIIAA%3D%3D):

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct t1 : protected T
{
};

template<typename T>
struct t2
{
    template<auto Index>
    struct inner : t1<T>
    {
    private:
        template<auto I>
            requires(Index == I)
        [[nodiscard]] friend constexpr const T& get(const inner& t) noexcept
        {
            return t;
        }
    };
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct t3 : t2<T>::template inner<0>, t2<U>::template inner<1>
{
};

void foo()
{
    const t3<false_type, tuple<int, float>> v{};
    auto v1 = get<0>(v);
    auto v2 = get<1>(v);
}
```

The type `inner` has a hidden `friend get`, but `std::tuple` also has `std::get` in global function, which emits the following errors.

Clang output:

> <source>:34:15: error: call to 'get' is ambiguous
>
> auto v1 = get<0>(v);
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.0.1/../../../../include/c++/13.0.1/tuple:1795:5: note: candidate function [with __i = 0, _Elements = <int, float>]
> get(const tuple<_Elements...>& __t) noexcept
>
> <source>:19:49: note: candidate function [with I = 0]
>
> [[nodiscard]] friend constexpr const T& get(const inner& t) noexcept

GCC gives the similar errors:

> <source>: In function 'void foo()':
>
> <source>:34:21: error: call of overloaded 'get<0>(const t3<std::integral_constant<bool, false>, std::tuple<int, float> >&)' is ambiguous
>
> auto v1 = get<0>(v);
>
> In file included from :1:
>
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230312/include/c++/13.0.1/tuple:1795:5: note: candidate:
>
> 'constexpr std::__tuple_element_t<__i, std::tuple<_UTypes ...> >& std::get(const tuple<_UTypes ...>&) [with long unsigned int __i = 0; _Elements = {int, float}; __tuple_element_t<__i, tuple<_UTypes ...> > = int]'
>
> get(const tuple<_Elements...>& __t) noexcept
>
> <source>:19:49: note: candidate: 'constexpr const T& get(const t2::inner&) [with auto I = 0; auto Index = 0; T = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
>
> [[nodiscard]] friend constexpr const T& get(const inner& t) noexcept

Surprisingly, MSVC accept the code.

If we replace `struct t1 : protected T` with `struct t1 : private T`, MSVC will print:

> error C2243: 'type cast': conversion from 'const t2::inner<0> *' to 'const T &' exists, but is inaccessible

The [adl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) description in cppreference.com says:

> ...
>
> Otherwise, for every argument in a function call expression its type is examined to determine the associated set of namespaces and classes that it will add to the lookup.
>
> 1. For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty
> 2. For arguments of class type (including union), the set consists of
>
> a) The class itself
>
> **b) All of its direct and indirect base classes**
>
> c) If the class is a member of another class, the class of which it is a member
>
> d) The innermost enclosing namespaces of the classes added to the set
>
> ...

In conclusion, compiler instantiates the `std::get` for `std::tuple` using `inner` as argument without access check, am I right?
But how can my hidden friend `get` be invoked under such inheritance without compile errors?

Comment: Yes, name lookup (including ADL) doesn't consider accessibility, which is considered even after overload resolution.

Comment: For design perspective, I prefer composition over inheritance. Is there any challenge preventing you from making `std::tuple` as an member variable of `t3` instead of inheritance?

Comment: @LouisGo I hope the empty base optimization was kept under inheritance